# How can I force a specific resolution in WebRTC regardless of network condition?

Tags: html, streaming, webrtc, rtp, sdp

I'm trying to dump WebRTC traffic into a container, **but with a consistent resolution**. To do that, there should be a way to encourage a browser to do so. By default, `Chrome` in particular adjusts the resolution to `320x240` when I'm in severe network condition. What I've found so far are:

1. to pass a constraint to `getUserMedia()` whose `width` & `height` are tagged as `exact` as in [this example](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#example-9), and
2. to add  `RTP Payload Format Restrictions` to `SDP` lines relating to `width` & `height`.

So, the former is not that related to the internal encoder inside the browser so that the resolution is still being dropped to `320x240`. Also, for the second solution, [the RFC specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-mmusic-rid-15#section-10) does not provide `min-width` & `min-height` as opposed to `max-width` & `min-width`, so no hopes there.

Answer (score -2):

There are new Syntaxes already tried it with those?

```
  var constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
                deviceId: device.id ? {exact: device.id} : undefined,
                width: {exact: candidate.width},    //new syntax
                height: {exact: candidate.height}   //new syntax
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: How’s that different from the first method I tried above?